# Update data from a form to table

Tags: php, mysql, forms, post

I have a form on a page that gets information from a table in my database. I want to be able to change the information in the from, and post it so it updates the table with the new information.

So far I got the form working, and getting the info from the table displayed in it as well. But I can't get the from to update the info to the table; I press the update button, and I get a success reply, but the info is the same as before. It's not updating - I get no errors or warnings from the code.

This is the form:

```
<span id="main-content">

<?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM settings WHERE id=1"; 
    if(!$result = $db->query($sql)){
        die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
    }

    if(!empty($_POST)) {
        update_settings($_POST['info']);
    }



    if ($result = mysqli_query($db, $sql)) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo "<form action='' method='POST'>";
            echo "<label>Overskrift</label>";
            echo "<textarea name='info' required>".$row['info']."</textarea>";
            echo "<input type='submit' value='Update'>";
            echo "</form>";
        }

        mysqli_free_result($result);
    }


    mysqli_close($db);
?>
```

And here is the function its sending it to.

```
//UPDATE SETTINGS
function update_settings($info) {
    global $db;

    $query = "UPDATE settings SET info = '$info' WHERE id = '$1'";
    $result = $db->query($query);

    echo "<div class='success wow fadeInDown'><b>Success:</b> Dit oplæg er nu opdateret.</div>";
}
```

Comment: There's lots wrong here, but specifically, in your `UPDATE` query `$1` should just be `1`.

Comment: Also, you seem to be using both procedural and object-oriented style with mysqli. Probably best to stick with one.

Comment: Mine W. That worked.... With all the hair i pulled i can barely believe it was only that little thing :)